# Split comma separated values into rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

This is my data:
[image: Orig data]

Using the method Data->Text to columns->Transpose do not work in this case. I need to convert comma separated values into each individual row AND have the other columns data duplicated to match. Like a SQL table. Maybe there is a macro that can do this.

Below is my desired result:
[image: Desired result]

Comment: *Maybe there is a macro that can do this* - There sure is :) And maybe you can write it. And if you get stuck, we can most probably even help you here. However, with a specific *programming* question and defined *programming* problem, there's not much we can do, as this is not a "code for me" service site.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your screen shots, but I think this concept will work for you.

```
Option Explicit

'Qual coluna possui os termos que repetem?
Const ANALYSIS_ROW As String = "K"

'Em qual linha começam os dados?
Const DATA_START_ROW As Long = 2

Sub ReplicateData()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iSplit() As String
    Dim iIndex As Long
    Dim iSize As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    End With

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ANALYSIS_ROW).End(xlUp).Row
    End With


    For iRow = LastRow To DATA_START_ROW Step -1
        iSplit = Split(ws.Cells(iRow, ANALYSIS_ROW).Value2, ",")
        iSize = UBound(iSplit) - LBound(iSplit) + 1
        If iSize = 1 Then GoTo Continue

        ws.Rows(iRow).Copy
        ws.Rows(iRow).Resize(iSize - 1).Insert
        For iIndex = LBound(iSplit) To UBound(iSplit)
            ws.Cells(iRow, ANALYSIS_ROW).Offset(iIndex).Value2 = iSplit(iIndex)
        Next iIndex
Continue:
    Next iRow

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```